# Will a neutered cat continue to mount a female in heat?

Tags: cats, behavior, desexing

Is the mounting behavior solely hormonal, or will her scent be enough to drive him to it? Would getting a cat neutered have any effect on the behavior?

[image]

Comment: Neutering definitely decreases the behavior A LOT, but it probably won't be 100%. Still I suggest neutering any cats and dogs you have. There are tons of benefits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, no, neutering a male cat will not eliminate mounting or territorial behavior (spraying).

It will, as Jeremy said in his comment, greatly reduce the behavior.

Some males will not mount or spray after being neutered, others will. I've seen the whole spectrum. It seems to depend at least partially on how experienced the cat is with these behaviors - males neutered before they fully mature seem to be less likely to spray or mount than those who are neutered after maturity.