# Neutered male cat still trying to mate?

Tags: cats, behavior, desexing

Our 8 month old male cat was neutered this morning. Back at home after surgery, still slightly groggy, he immediately attempted to mate with his mother, at least 3 times within an hour.

Why would he do that when he is in pain and drugged? I thought neutering was meant to immediately quell that desire?

Comment: Does the answer to this question: http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6003/will-a-neutered-cat-continue-to-mount-a-female-in-heat?rq=1 help? I've seen neutered males try to mount neutered females in what appears to be an attempt to assert leadership. Cats may not have the pack instinct dogs have, but they still have a hierarchy when you have more than one cat in a smallish area.

Comment: All of those hormones are still in his system.  In my experience with house rabbits it can take 2-4 weeks for behavior to be modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

His body is no longer producing hormones, but those that are already in his body take some time to work out.

### Details

North Shore Animal League America's SpayUSA is a nationwide network and referral service for affordable spay/neuter. [They state](http://spayusa.org/pet-owners-faq.php):

> It usually takes about 6 to 8 weeks for the hormones to subside after the neutering.

Bruce Fogle, D.V.M., M.R.C.V.S [relates the results](http://maxshouse.com/effects_of_neutering.htm) of one study:

> Ben Hart at the University of California veterinary school at Davis was the first to investigate the value of neutering male cats. He interviewed cat owners twenty-three months after their cats had been castrated. The owners reported that in nine out of ten animals neutering reduced fighting, roaming and spraying. Sometimes the change took longer than in others, and by Hart's definition a 'rapid decline' meant within three weeks of neutering and a 'gradual decline' meant one that took up to four months.

The results showed that about 50% of the neutered cats had a rapid decline in fighting and aggression, and about 10-15% of the neutered cats had a gradual decline in fighting and aggression. Spraying behavior was reduced faster (about 75% rapid decline, 10% gradual decline).