# Cat - how much time do anti-heat injections take to start having an effect?

Tags: cats, medicines, veterinarian

Our male cat was yowling several times a day. It was really annoying. According to vet it was due to heat cycle. We have been facing his loud yowling for months now, so vet asked us for neuter or anti heat injection. Today we took him to vet for anti-heat injection, but the cat is still yowling. May I know how much time it will take to start having an effect?

Comment: "heat cycle"? in a *male* cat?? Someone's very confused here ...

Comment: tell me senpai, this is my first pet

Comment: so my male cat doesnot go in heat cycle ? why is he yowling so loud and why vet asks me to neuter?

Comment: *Female* animals have a "heat cycle". An un-neutered male will respond and be attracted to a female in heat. A neutered male won't care (much) if there's a nearby female in heat..

Comment: why is he yowling so loud? if heat is not the case then why vet asked me for anti heat injection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not clear from your description which drug was used for the "anti heat injection".  But some of them can be partially effective for male cats.  I would imagine it could take several weeks to become as effective as it can be, and it will need to be given repeatedly to have a long term impact.

Your best solution may be neuter [as suggested by Flummox](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/20597/13) even the surgey may not be 100% effective see related [Will a neutered cat continue to mount a female in heat?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6003/will-a-neutered-cat-continue-to-mount-a-female-in-heat)

> Medroxyprogesterone acetate (MPA) is a synthetic progesterone. It is commonly used in humans as a form of birth control, and it may also be used in pets to suppress heat cycles. It can also be used to treat behavior problems such as aggression, spraying or marking.
>
> Progesterone is a sex hormone found naturally in pets. At high doses, synthetic progesterone can prevent the ovaries from producing eggs. At smaller doses, it may slightly alter your pet’s behavior. **It reduces sex drive in males**, making them less likely to be aggressive towards other males. Also, if you have a male pet that roams in search of a mate, MPA can prevent this behavior. [Source](https://www.petmd.com/pet-medication/medroxyprogesterone-acetate)

Answer (score 6):

Note, this is not a direct answer to your question, but will address the yowling.

**If you have a male cat and do not intent to breed with it, please neuter him.**

[Pro's and cons of neutering.](https://www.catster.com/lifestyle/spay-neuter-cats-debate)

And I assume there is a female cat somewhere near that your cat would like to mate with. As long as she is in heat, he will yowl for / at her.

Comment: we have 1 female but he has already dealt with her, why he is still yowling knowing that she wont mate again until she gives birth

Comment: there are 2 stray cats sitting outside our house, both are female. Is this the reason he is still yowling ?

Comment: @DaniyalJavaid I would think so. Nothing else will start and keep a male cat yowling.

Comment: isn't anti-heat injection a temporary alternative to neuter? cat should stop yowling within next 2 days or I am taking him to vet again

Comment: Can I let my pet mate with stray cat? Cats outside are dirty and unhygienic

Comment: @DaniyalJavaid your comment inspired me to post the question [Can a cat get a sexaullly transmitted disease?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/20601/can-a-cat-get-a-sexaullly-transmitted-disease)