# Can a cat get a sexually transmitted disease?

Tags: cats, breeding, diseases

If my normally indoor cat mates with a feral cat, is it at risk of getting any diseases?

My cat has all of its vaccines up to date, so I suspect the only concern would be a sexually transmitted disease.

Inspired by a [comment](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/20593/cat-how-much-time-does-anti-heat-injections-take-to-take-effect/20597#comment27993_20597) at the question [Cat - How much time does anti-heat injections take to take effect?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/20593/cat-how-much-time-does-anti-heat-injections-take-to-take-effect)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to this is yes this do happen but sex is only one way cats can get infected other types of close contact can spread diseases too.

- Feline herpes can be transmitted by body fluids.
- FIV cat aids can be transmitted by body fluids.
- Feline chlamydia can be transmitted by body fluids,
- Panelukopenia virus can be transmitted by body fluids.
- Calcivirus can be transmitted by body fluids.
- Catflu can be transmitted by body fluids
- Rabies can definitely be transmitted by body fluids and not only to other cats but to all types of animals including humans.

I assume there is several other types of illness that can be transmitted by body fluids not only from intercourse but from bites too.

Source for some of it http://wtvr.com/2013/04/30/cat-stds-on-the-rise/

Source two my cats vaccination card the standard vaccines given to cats here in Norway.

Comment: Herpesvirus, feline **immunodeficiency** virus (FIV), and **Chlamydia** are not considered STDs in cats. These viruses as well as **panleukopenia**, **calicivirus**, and catflu, are all transmitted by close contact or bites, and no sexual contact is needed for transmission. Your first "source" is just a news article written by someone who saw "herpes" and thought "sex".

Comment: you are right and it is why i say body fluids and not from sex,and the source is a realy bad one but it is still a source :)